# How do I beat Bowser?

Tags: luigis-mansion

In Luigi's Mansion, there is a part where you encounter King Boo and he transforms into Bowser. Bowser is a very difficult boss to beat, so can anyone tell me how to beat him?

Comment: The gamecube tag isn't really needed, dude.  The game only came out for Gamecube, so it's sort of redundant.

Comment: I know. I just felt like putting it there because the gamecube tag is feeling lonely.

Comment: I'd recommend removing it; we try to keep the site neat, and using it in that manner violates that organization.

Comment: Okay sorry for violating the organization in this manner.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Beating Bowser is a simple two-step process:

> 1. Vacuum up the spikebombs he tosses at you and blast them back at his face while he bends down and tries to vacuum you. This makes King Boo appear.
> 2. Vacuum King Boo until he retreats.

Repeat. The rest is just avoiding his attacks: fire breath has short range and charges move in straight lines. The ice breath is a bit tougher to avoid but won't hit you if you keep moving.

Comment: nice block quote.

Comment: You can also make King Boo appear by blasting a spikebomb in Bowser's face when he bends down to breath fire, not just when he bends to try and vacuum you.